# What best way to have same two app with different names

Tags: android, git

I have app on git with package for example `com.foo`.

Now I want to create clone of this app with different name.

In order to do it I fork my app and change the name. But this app has the same package.

And I can't install the second app because they have same package name.

What would be the best way to support two apps with same functions but different names?

Comment: I don't know how would you go about changing package on git but if you want to apps to run on the same device then simply change its `applicationId` in your app level `build.gradle`.

Comment: However as @Jd Prajapati has pointed out using flavors is a lot better.

Comment: I tried change applicationId. But i get the same error. But i don't rename package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create different productFlavors for another app in same code

```
productFlavors {
        VersionFirst {
            applicationId "packagename"
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        VersionSecond {
            applicationId "packagename"
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

generate different build using build varient

Comment: I tried it. And get the same error that app with this package already installed.

Comment: did you change the build variant and generate different build?

Comment: yes that's fine but you need to set also build varients for generate different build

Comment: I don't understand. If i build app that have in AndroidManifest package name com.foo but with different applicationId. Can i install both app? Or the second app will replace first ?

Comment: thanks! you are right! My problem was not package name ;) i have file provider and it has same names. I change names for file provider and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If two applications have the same package name, only one of them will be installed. If they share the same signature, installing the second package will overwrite the first assuming it doesn't downgrade the version. If they have different signatures, you'll get an error saying that you can't install the second package.

Read this :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html